# Determining convergence/divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I am studying for my exam tomorrow and have come across some problems I cannot get. I have put them below with what I have tried/thinking process behind. Thank you.

```
1. Sum from 1 to infinity of ( 1 / (n + 2^n) )
```

I feel like I was supposed to use the comparison test for this one, but I don't know whether I should compare it to 1/n or 1/ 2^n, or even 1 / n + 2^n. Which one?

```
2. Sum from 1 to infinity of (n! / n^n)
```

I remember in class that whenever I see n!, I should be thinking to use the ratio test in order to have some n! cancel out. So I did this and I got this: (an/bn) = (an * bn reciprocal)

```
(n+1)!         *       n^n
______               ________
(n+1)^(n+1)             n!
```

So would the next step be to split the (n+1)! up into (n) and (n!)? If so you get (and where I am stuck):

```
lim                   n^2n (?)
n--> infinity        __________
                      (n+1)^(n+1)
```

I get stuck here and don't really know how to evaluate that with l'hopitals rule.

Thanks again

Comment: For the first, compare with $\frac{1}{2^n}$. That gives a familiar convergent series.

Comment: For the second, Ratio Test will work nicely. Or else note that $n!/n^n=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{2}{n}\cdots\cdot \frac{n}{n}$. all the terms in the product are $\le 1$, the product of the first two is $\frac{2}{n^2}$, so the general term is $\le \frac{2}{n^2}$. Now use Comparison.

Comment: If i were to go the ratio test route, would the work I had in the original post be correct? Would I just have to do l'hopitals rule where I got stuck?

Comment: I had better write a part answer to deal with it, since the same idea is useful for the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment we described a simple Comparison approach to the second question. Here is an alternative using the Ratio Test.

As in the post, the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ of consecutive terms is
$$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot \frac{n^n}{n!}.$$

Cancel an $n+1$ from top and bottom of the first fraction. Things simplify to
$$\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}$$.

This is the reciprocal of $\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n$, that is, of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, which has limit $e$ as $n\to\infty$.

It follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{e}\lt 1$, so we have convergence.

**Remark:** One can exploit the expression of $e$ as a limit to show that the terms in the third problem blow up as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So (n+1)! got broken down into n! and n+1? Makes sense

Comment: Yes. And the $n!$ cancelled the $n!$ at the bottom, while the remaining $n+1$ cancelled one of the $n+1$ in $(n+1)^{n+1}$, leaving $(n+1)^n$. That's why the whole thing simplifies as in the next displayed formula.